# How to translate "school bullying" and "bully"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Long time ago, I found a good word about bullying. It is not *ĉagreni* because it is longer, but it is not *turmenti* because it is milder. I would like to find the word and to adapt it to mean "school bullying", and then adapt it again to mean "school bully".

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way to capture “to bully” is the verb *ĉikan·i*. **PIV** defines it as:

> Intence fari al iu maljustajn ĝenojn, malagrablaĵojn, malhelpojn, por sentigi al li/ŝi sian superecon.

So “a bully” would be *ĉikan·ant·o*, if it's a person who was bullying in a moment we're talking about, or *ĉikan·ul·o*, if it's a person who often bullies other people. The noun “bullying” would be *ĉikan·ad·o*, which is the translation used in [the Esperanto Wikipedia](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%88ikanado).

Comment: That's just one of several definitions in PIV. Wells glosses it as "to quibble." The definition you cite seems more like hazing than bullying.

Comment: ĉikan·ant·o is perfect in my opinion

Answer (score 2):

Wells and Benson (CEED) - both dictionaries worth having in your library - list *tirani* for "to bully." Wells also has *brutali.*

From PIV (vortaro.net):

- *brutal/o. Krudaĉa, perfortema, kruela homo*
- *tiran/o. [...] Ordonema k senindulga mastro*